# Full Linux distro under 50 MB for a business card CD

Tags: dvd, small-distribution, data-cd, distribution-media

I need a full Linux distribution for a non-profit activist organisation that can fit on a business card CD.

If that's not possible, there is a business card DVD option too with up to 400 MB capacity.

But I would really prefer CD over DVD if such spartan Linux distribution under 50 MB exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for DSL http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/

Comment: DSL lists booting from a business card CD as an explicit goal.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Tiny Core Linux](http://tinycorelinux.net) is an option for you.